# Get item from list collection in asp.net session + object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session

I created a SessionManager class in order to handle my session variables in an asp.net application. Following is a piece of my SessionManager class code:

```
    public int TotalTests
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["totalTests"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["totalTests"] = value;
        }
    }

    public List<TestCase> TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<TestCase>)HttpContext.Current.Session["testCases"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["testCases"] = value;
        }
    }
```

The issue is that I am able to set and access the value of TotalTests from both code-behind and other classes in my web app. However with the regard to the TestsCases i am able to assign a collection of List type from code-behind, and debugging the application shows that the Session variable is actually getting populated, however when i try to retrieve an item from the collection stored in session using LINQ i get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error. the code i'm using is the below:

```
TestCase test = (from testCase in session.TestCases
                        where testCase.testName == result.Name
                        select testCase).Single();
```

And to populate the the collection in session i used

SessionManager session = new SessionManager();
session.TestCases = testCases;

Any idea please what might be causing this?

Comment: Is your object ref on the LINQ statement itself, or when you try and access the "test" object? Also, are you sure "result" is not null?

Comment: I've set a breakpoint.  when creating an instance of the SessionManager class the session object is showing the following exception:

'session.TestCases' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
'session.TotalTests' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'


I'm creating this instance on TestFinished method of a class called NunitEventListener which inherits from the nunit interface NUnit.Core.EventListener, could it be that it's actually creating a new session when this method is called, thus it finds the session list empty?

Comment: Aha, it's best to mention things like NUnit in your question as that could be the problem as it works in different contexts potentially - so, yes, I believe a completely new Session is being called in your Test Cases and thus the list will be empty.

Comment: hmm that's what i thought also. what i had in mind is to access the list of tests in the collection stored in session and set their result on testfinished event and then access the collection in session again from webmethod to show results in ui. So i think the only is to get the results directly from the database as i'm currently doing. My plan was to actually find a way so as not to have a lot of requests to the sql database in order to the get results and have everything stored in memory.

Comment: That's what I'd do, avoid Sessions where you can and do quick data retrieval from the database with small calls.